# Regular expression won't match special character in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I do not understand why the following code snippet returns false. I understand that special characters must be escaped, but *re.escape()* already does that.

```
import re

string = re.escape('$') 
pattern = re.compile(string)
print(bool(pattern.match(string)))
```

Comment: Match is supposed to match from the start of the string. Your string is `\$`, `\ ` is not `$`.

Comment: @SebastianProske I don't understand lol. I used the same string for the pattern and the string to be matched.

Comment: The regex `\$` matches a literal `$`, your string doesn't start with `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping the wrong one. The string to be searched does not need to be modified. But strings you include in the pattern to be matched literally do.

```
import re

string = '$'
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(string))
print(bool(pattern.match(string)))
```

Here, pattern `\$` (match literal `$`) is matched against the string `"$"`, and succeeds.

In your example, the pattern `\$` (match literal `$`) is matched against the string `"\$"` (`r"\$"` or `"\\$"` in Python), and fails because `match` requires the pattern to cover the entire string, and the backslash is left unmatched.